# Kendo Components are not rendered correctly in angular-cli

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am following the Kendo tutorial for Angular2. I have scaffolded my project using the angular-cli tool. I successfully enabled the Progress NPM registry. I successfully installed and tested the button widget in the tutorial's "Getting Started" section. I then downloaded and tested several of the other components, including the Chart, Grid, Dropdowns and Dialogs. I was unable to get any of these components to display correctly:

The Dialog and Grid only displayed the textual contents but not the graphics of the widget (window, lines, colors, etc.). The dropdown appeared as an empty text box with no dropdown arrow.

As an example, here is how one of the Chart component examples appeared:

[kendo barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhF9Y.jpg)

This is my app.module.ts code:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; //
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; //
    import { ChartsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
          AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          FormsModule,  
          HttpModule,  
          ChartsModule
      ],
      providers: [],  //
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

And this is my Component code:

```
    import {Component} from "@angular/core";

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      styleUrls: ['./../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-charts/dist/npm/css/main.css'],
      template: `
            <button (click)="toggleSeries()">Toggle second series</button>
            <kendo-chart [transitions]="showTransitions">
              <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="[1, 2, 3, 5]">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
                <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="[5, 3, 2, 1]" *ngIf="showSeries">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
              </kendo-chart-series>
            </kendo-chart>
        `
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      private showSeries: boolean = false;
      private showTransitions: boolean = true;

      private toggleSeries() {
        this.showSeries = !this.showSeries;
        this.showTransitions = false;
      }
    }
```

SOLVED THE PROBLEM:
As described in the Kendo getting started tutorial, installed the styles css

```
    npm install -S @telerik/kendo-theme-default
```

But, rather than referencing it from the Component, I put it in the angular-cli.json file:

```
    {
      "project": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta.17",
        "name": "kairos-cli"
      },
      "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": "assets",
          "index": "index.html",
          "main": "main.ts",
          "test": "test.ts",
          "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
          "prefix": "app",
          "mobile": false,
          "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
          ],
          ...
```

Comment: If you can add your solution as an answer, you should be able to mark this question as closed

Comment: We'll update the Getting Started instructions to use angular-cli.json as this approach seems to be more reliable.